# How to use Google DataFlow Runner and Templates in tf.Transform?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-ml, apache-beam, google-cloud-ml-engine

We are in the process of establishing a Machine Learning pipeline on Google Cloud, leveraging GC ML-Engine for distributed TensorFlow training and model serving, and DataFlow for distributed pre-processing jobs.

We would like to run our Apache Beam apps as DataFlow jobs on Google Cloud. looking at the [ML-Engine samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/criteo_tft/preprocess.py)
 it appears possible to get **tensorflow_transform.beam.impl AnalyzeAndTransformDataset** to specify which **PipelineRunner** to use as follows:

```
from tensorflow_transform.beam import impl as tft
pipeline_name = "DirectRunner"
p = beam.Pipeline(pipeline_name) 
p | "xxx" >> xxx | "yyy" >> yyy | tft.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset(...)
```

[TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner) provides the ability to separate our preprocessing development from parameterized operations - see here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/overview - basically:

- A) in **PipelineOptions** derived types, change option types to **ValueProvider** (python way: type inference or type hints ???)
- B) change runner to **TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner**
- C)  **mvn archetype:generate** to store template in GCS (python way: a yaml file like TF Hypertune ???)
- D) **gcloud beta dataflow jobs run --gcs-location —parameters**

The question is: Can you show me how we can we use **tf.Transform** to leverage **TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python templates are available as of April 2017 (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/overview)). The way to operate them is the following:

- Define UserOptions subclassed from PipelineOptions.
- Use the add_value_provider_argument API to add specific arguments to be parameterized.
- Regular non-parameterizable options will continue to be defined using argparse's add_argument.

```
class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
     @classmethod
     def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
         parser.add_value_provider_argument('--value_provider_arg', default='some_value')
         parser.add_argument('--non_value_provider_arg', default='some_other_value')
```

Note that Python doesn't have a TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner, and neither does Java 2.X (unlike what happened in Java 1.X).

Comment: Looking at the java **TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner class** ( https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner.java ) , it encapsulates **DataflowPipelineRunner**

- How hard would it be to create a custom python runner that encapsulated the apache beam python API **class DataflowRunner(PipelineRunner)** ( https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/0.6.0/_modules/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.html#DataflowRunner) ?

Comment: The TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner is not part of Beam either. For Dataflow customers, the way to create a template in Java is choosing a runner for 1.x or passing a templateLocation for 2.x. For python, it will be passing a template_location. For more information about templates, visit https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/overview. Note that the documentation pertains 1.x until 2.0, currently in beta, is released.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Python pipelines cannot be used as templates. It is only available for Java [today](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/overview). Since you need to use the python library, it will not be feasible to do this.

tensorflow_transform would also need to support ValueProvider so that you can pass in options as a value provider type through it.